# SpringBoot WhiteLabel error on change package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is demoApplication class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this is the controller

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    Response hellow() {
        return new Response("Hello World!");
    }

    class Response{
        private String message;

        Response(String message){
            this.setMessage(message);
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

if I place the controller on package `com.example.demo.controllers` works, but if I place it on `com.example.controllers` I get a whiteLabelError ,I supose in `com.example.controllers` the controller is not found,what I have to set to place the controller on `com.example.controllers` and it works?

Comment: just check in your configuration files. do you have it hardcoded set somewhere, in a path or xml file? do you set your config to only search for beans in that particular (sub)package?

Comment: I haven't set anything

Comment: either you have configured it somewhere, or you don't correct your import statements, or this makes very little sense. it shouldn't check whether or not a class is in a certain package, just whether it has access to it

Comment: And whre are the configuration files?(I'm new on spring)

Comment: It's your configuration/project. I'm used to the xml config version, which works differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your main class `DemoApplication` that is annotated as `@SpringBootApplication` (hides `@ComponentScan` underneath [as you can see in the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L52)) lives under package `com.example.demo` and scans by default all classes under this package and all packages underneath.

So just move `DemoApplication` one level higher under the `com.example` package and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because your class `DemoApplication` in package `com.example.demo`. Package of controllers depends package of your SpringBoot main file.